# NG-CHANGE won't fire on alertify popup window instance

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm building a settings modal window using alertify.js  to change the image back ground of a page, but when the alertify.js creates an instance of the of the html containing my dropdown then the select loses the ng-change functionality but if the dropdown is on the page then it works.

choose anything from the dropdown you will get an alert fired by

> ng-change="main.unitChanged() "
>   but no on the modal window

how can I make this work with ng-change when the window is popup ??

PLUNKER [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/ghRN2CYazTKoX2eTBT6J?p=preview)

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  var self = this;

  self.backGroundSelected = 'Balloon';

  self.fontSizes = [
    '8',
    '14',
    '20'
  ];

  self.unitChanged = function(selectedOption) {
    alert(selectedOption);
  };

  self.changeBackground = [
    'Balloon',
    'Billboard',
    'BusStop',
    'GirlWithBalloons',
    'GreenField',
    'NatureCouple',
    'RedFlowers',
    'PrescriptionPad',
    'SeniorMan',
    'SunCouple',
    'Victory',
    'WhiteFlowers',
    'WomanWithTree',
  ];

  self.typeOfFont = [
    'Serif',
    'Sans-serif',
    'Roboto'
  ];

  self.legendAboutOption = function() {
    alertify.alert(document.getElementById("configuration").innerHTML).set('title', 'Back-Ground Settings').set('transition', 'pulse').set('resizable', true).resizeTo('35%', '70%');

  }


});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/alertifyjs/1.4.1/css/alertify.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/alertifyjs/1.4.1/css/themes/default.min.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.17/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.17"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/alertifyjs/1.4.1/alertify.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
  <div class="btn-group" role="group">

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary   glyphicon glyphicon-cog" ng-click="main.legendAboutOption()">Display Window</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
  </div>



  <!--Templates For modal box-->
  <div class="container-fluid" id="configuration" style="display:block">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-2">
                <span class="label label-default">Backgrounds:Will fire an alert on ng-change</span>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <select ng-model="myBackGround" ng-change="main.unitChanged(myBackGround)" ng-options="BackGround for BackGround in main.changeBackground">
                  <option value="">Choose Template</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-7">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: **Side Note** For safer side..you should use different ng-model name as you were using BackGround in your ng-options..

Comment: @Pankaj Parkar  I did change the ng-model but the ng-change event still no attaching on the popup window and I need that event to fire to get the dropdown value selected.

Comment: why do don't think about the modal popup like `ui-bootstrap` modal..

Comment: I did, that's how I actually solve the problem but i was hoping someone made it work with alertify js. I end up doing a modal box with a controller and I use a service to get and set the values from the modal box, but with the ng-change I was able to do it with the creation of any service at all.@PankajParkar

Answer (score 1):

The reason your event stops firing inside the modal is because you are creating a new copy of the view, you should pass the view element itself.

[Updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZZ6UNWGLOelQ0oL9qhzj?p=preview)

```
self.legendAboutOption = function(){
    alertify.alert(document.getElementById("configuration"))
            .set({'title': 'Background Settings','transition':'pulse','resizable':true})
            .resizeTo('35%', '70%');
}
```

Comment: Thanks why I did not think about that jeje